# Jquery: Hidden top menu, slide up on paused mouse movement

Tags: jquery, mousemove

I'm creating a header menu that slides down when you move the mouse within in the browser window.

But I want to have it slide up after the mouse hasn't moved for 5 seconds.

Here is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/BEzbw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery throttle/debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) is a great plugin for doing things like this safely. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BEzbw/14/)

```
$('html').mousemove( $.debounce( 250, true, function(e){
        $('header').animate({ top: '0' }, 300)
    }))
    .mousemove( $.debounce( 5000, false, function(e){
        $('header').animate({ top: '-60px' }, 300)
    }));
```

ps: bear in mind that attaching to `<html>` in that way could get your event blocked by other page elements (although unlikely for a mousemove event).

Answer (score 0):

give this a try

http://jsfiddle.net/lastrose/BEzbw/3/

might need to work on the timing though

Comment: This is close to what I need, but even when you move the mouse around the page, the header bounces. The header should slide up only when the mouse has stopped moving.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$(document).ready( function () {

    $('header').css('top', '-60px');
    $('html').mousemove(function(event) {
        $('header').animate({ top: '0' }, 300);
    });

    //Increment the idle time counter every second.
    idleTime = 0;
    var idleInterval = setInterval("timerIncrement()", 6000);

    //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
    $(this).keypress(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });

    function timerIncrement() {
        idleTime = idleTime + 1;
        if (idleTime > 4) { // 5sec
            $('header').animate({ top: '-60px' }, 300);
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: This is very close, but the slide up doesn't seem to be firing. Here is the above code running: http://jsfiddle.net/FAtUw/